# Server 2008 Terminal Server + Outlook 2007. I need to change the default font used in Outlook

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, outlook-2007, microsoft-office

Server 2008 used as terminal server with Office 2007 installed.  I've been asked to deploy a GPO to make the default font used Veranda 11 for all Office Suite applications.

I've been doing some research and the success with this seems hit or miss.  I need to know if there is a way for me to easily force this for all user accounts on the terminal server.  if I have to update HKCU for each user I will but will be a major hassle for all new users added.

Answer (score 0):

User login script on that machine to make the registry change locally when they login? Or perhaps add it to the startup group for all users on that machine.  It's not elegant, but "it has teeth".  Should be able to script that change from the command line....

Comment: Problem with logon script is it would run each time the user logs into the TS.  I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: just sorta brainstorming.  Is it possible to add an item to the "RunOnce" hive instead?  Something like this?  https://support.microsoft.com/kb/284193 which sets the "RunOnce" flag and then execute what you need to do, it will only run on the first login so you should be all set then.

Comment: @Mike66350216 You can always set the GPO that will apply each time a user logs in, and then remove the GPO after everyone's logged in, though you might be making too much of that being a problem.  So what if it applies when it's not needed?  You've probably made the logon process take an extra 50 ms or so, and... well, so what?  To me, that's worth it to make sure the policy is applied to everyone, and stays applied to everyone, especially if someone is making a big deal about this policy being in place.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for - a GPO that will accomplish this.  I'd prefer a GPO over a logon script for obvious reasons.

Comment: I'm about to ask a noob question here.  Can you apply a HKCU GPO targeted at only one machine?  In his case the Terminal Server.  Wouldn't the GPO apply to any machine the user logged into because of where it sits in the registry hive?

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't pose a big problem.

Stick your remote desktop session host in an OU and link a GPO to the OU.

Configure your GPO thusly: 
Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > System > Group Policy > User Group Policy loopback processing mode - Enabled

[This will enable you to link the GPO to a Computer but have it apply the User settings of the GPO, see here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2013/02/08/circle-back-to-loopback.aspx You can also use a separate GPO to enable loopback policy processing on your RDSH, ie you don't have to specify it in each GPO linked to the computer]

User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Registry > New Registry Item > [configure as required] > Common: tick 'Apply once and do not re-apply'

That should work?  The registry settings required will probably be under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\XXX\Common\MailSettings